# Matrix column based on slicer selection in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 dropdowns called MENU 1 and MENU 2 , both created using column pagename

Now i have to create a matrix where MENU1 and MENU2 should be columns and count of visits, count of visitors, count of downloads should be values.

The challenge here is if i select some value in dropdown MENU1 and dropdown MENU2, then same should reflect in matrix column and count of visits, count of visitors, count of downloads should be updated accordingly based on my dropdown values selection

I have tried creating measure using selectedvalue function for the value selected in slicer but cannot use measure in mateix column

Comment: Hi, what is in your MENU1 and MENU2? If possible, could you show us some image as your question is unclear.

Comment: Don’t show an images but copyable sample data!